# Using DISTINCT and COUNT in a query

Tags: count, distinct, google-bigquery

I'm having issues using `DISTINCT` and `COUNT` in the same query. I would like to get unique items then get a total count for each month. (I've done this in two queries but I know there's a better way.)

**Query:**

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', Sell_Date) AS Sell_Date,
  count(*) Total_Sold
FROM
  `project.dataset.items`
GROUP BY
  Sell_Date
ORDER BY
  Sell_Date
```

**Results (snippet):**

```
Row     Sell_Date   Total_Sold   
 1       2010-05        15   
 2       2010-06        40  
 3       2010-07        75  
 4       2010-08        20
```

This is what I would like, however, this contains duplicate `Item_Id` entries.

If I replace the `SELECT` above with this:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Item_Id,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', Sell_Date) AS Sell_Date,
```

I get this error:

> Error: SELECT list expression references column Item_Id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:12]

If I replace the `GROUP BY` with:

```
GROUP BY
      Sell_Date, Item_Id
```

Results (snippet):

```
Row     Item_Id      Sell_Date   Total_Sold  
 1       992         2010-05         1   
 2       118         2010-05         1   
 3       855         2010-05         1   
 4       846         2010-05         1   
 5       989         2010-05         1   
 6       505         2010-05         1   
 7       997         2010-05         1   
 8       983         2010-05         1   
 9       122         2010-05         1   
 10      601         2010-05         1   
 11      845         2010-05         1
```

How can I get `DISTINCT` items then count the total for each month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count (distinct item_id)`

---

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', Sell_Date) AS Sell_Date,
  count(*) Total_Sold,
  count (distinct item_id) as distinct_item_id 

FROM
  `project.dataset.items`
GROUP BY
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', Sell_Date) AS Sell_Date
ORDER BY
  Sell_Date
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Could you please add an explanation for me and for others who may be curious about what's happening here? Thanks again.

Comment: I believe you may actually need the group by to be "GROUP BY FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', Sell_Date)" since otherwise it will group by the unformatted sell_date.

Comment: Actually, this one is quiet straight-forward, COUNT(*) count all rows, COUNT(item_id) counts only item_ids that are not null, COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) counts item_ids that are not, but ignore duplicates of item_id. count (distinct x) where x is 10,20,10,20,20,10,30,20,10,20,30,10 will return 3 (10,20,30).

Comment: @MguerraTorres, I didn't work with google-bigquery and there is a good chance that you are right. Changed it. Thanks.

Comment: Good point. Very possible that big-query is just intuitive enough to allow the group by using the alias as a column.  If you're curious, try changing the alias to "sell_date1" and group by that instead.

Comment: @MguerraTorres correct, BigQuery allows aliases defined in the SELECT list to be used in GROUP BY.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - The question is what is what is being used when the alias is the same as a source column (Teradata for instance use the source column)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I don't know that. I guess a simple test with 2 rows having same year and month but different day/time would reveal what happens, by yielding 1 or 2  rows respectively. I don't have a bigquery installation to test.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, same here :-)

Comment: The results of the OP's first query suggest that it uses the alias. Unless all those 75 rows in July are from the same exact date and time!